# JQuery value second index

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una select y me gustaría obtener el `value` del segundo `option`. Me gustaría obtener el `value` 25, ahora me obtiene el `value` 0 porque es el primero.

```
<select id="datatable" >
    <option value="0">Sele...</option>
    <option value="71">25</option>
    <option value="72">12</option>
    <option value="73">14</option>
</select>

jQuery('#datatable').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes obtener solo el seleccionado con selected

ejemplo:

```
<select id="datatable" >
    <option value="0">Sele...</option>
    <option selected value="71">25</option>
    <option value="72">12</option>
    <option value="73">14</option>
</select>
```

obtiene el valor seleccionado

```
$("#datatable option:selected").val();
```

obtiene el contenido

```
$("#datatable option:selected").html();
```

si requieres seleccionar desde jquery

```
$("#datatable option[value=71]").attr("selected",true);
```

Comment: Lo necesito hacer por jquery. Porque este select se coje de una consulta a la bd

Comment: $("#datatable option:selected").val();

Answer (score 0):

Lo que haces con este codigo

```
jQuery('#datatable').val();
```

es obtener un valor de value del select en si, no del item seleccionado. Para obtener el value del item que seleccionas debes hacerlo de la siguiente manera (voy a intentar adaptarlo  a tu código):

```
('#datatable option:selected').val();
```

Espero haya resuelto tu duda.

**EDIT:**

Añado que si quieres obtener el texto y no el value tu código debe ser así:

```
('#datatable option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera, con la función `change` obtienes el valor cuando hagas el cambio, espero te funcione.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
    $('#datatable').change(function(){
    
    var dato = $(this).val();
    console.log(dato);
    })
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="datatable" >
        <option value="0">Sele...</option>
        <option value="71">25</option>
        <option value="72">12</option>
        <option value="73">14</option>
    </select>
```